# Remove render view in Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, bootstrap-modal, laravel-blade

I am working with Laravel and viewing some data in Bootstrap modal using Rander view.

I am opening the modal on click and getting render data in it.

Here is how I am randoing data in my controller:

```
$view = \View::make('list.modal-body', ['list'=>$list]);   
$message = $view->render();
return response()->json([
   ajax_request_return_data'          => $message
]);
```

I am getting this `$message` which is an HTML response to my Ajax request.
and then I am rendering this on a modal body.

Here is my HTML data which I am randoring:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table>
    <thead>
            <tr>
            </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
        @foreach($list as $single_detail)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $single_detail->detail_name }}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
     </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

and here Is the AJAX function which I am Using:

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : URL-OF-AJAX', 
    data : { 'related_data' : ralate_data_detail }, 
    success: function(data) {
        $('.CLASS_OF_Modal_Body').append(data.ajax_request_return_data)        
        $('#modal_id').modal('toggle');
    },
    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    
    }
});
```

**ISSUE**

**The issue is when I render data the old render data showing in the table with new data and it keeps adding on every time I open that modal**

**What possible solution I have tried?**

I have tried to pass the empty data before adding a new one but still shows old data in the modal table.

I have also tried to remove the view cache but still old data came in a table with new data.

Pelase help me on this how can I Randor FRESH data in the table every time and remove the old render data.

Comment: try using html instead of append   $('.CLASS_OF_Modal_Body').html(data.ajax_request_return_data)

Comment: @JohnLobo hey sir.. you solve it.. i get that problem is not in my controller or ajax request.. it's in the view append. thank you sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using append use html method.

Replace

```
 $('.CLASS_OF_Modal_Body').append(data.ajax_request_return_data)
```

to

```
  $('.CLASS_OF_Modal_Body').html(data.ajax_request_return_data)
```

Ref:

https://api.jquery.com/html/

https://api.jquery.com/append/